# posting activeCheckBox

Tags: checkbox, yii

I want to change `upload` value according to the check state of the checkbox, so if it is checked the value should be 1, else, the value should be 0.
here is the code in the controller:

```
$upload=isset($_POST['upload']);
            if($upload['value']==1){
                $model->upload=1;
                if($model->validate())
                $model->save();
            }
            else{
                $model->upload=0;
                if($model->validate())
                $model->save();
            }
```

and here is the code in the view:

```
CHtml::activeCheckBox($modelr[$j], 'upload', false, array ('value'=>1,'uncheckValue'=>0))
```

but in all cases the value of upload still 0
what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the controller code like so :

```
 if(isset($_POST['Upload'])){
    $upload=$_POST['upload'];
    if($upload == 1){
        $model->upload=1;
        if($model->validate())
            $model->save();
    }
    else{
        $model->upload=0;
        if($model->validate())
            $model->save();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the form is using the POST method?